# String representation of chess board

Tags: java

I need to print a chess board. In this example I create a board with `for` in `for` and did a `for each` where take chess pieces and put in it's places:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int number = 8; number >= 1; number--) {
            for (char letter = 'H'; letter >= 'A'; letter--) {
                
                for (ChessPiece chessPiece : pieces) {
                    if (chessPiece.getCell().letter == letter && chessPiece.getCell().number == number) {
                        stringBuilder.append(chessPiece.toChar());
                    }
                }
                }
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
            }
            String string = String.valueOf(stringBuilder);

            return string;
        }
```

The result is:

```
RNBQKBNR
PPPPPPPP




pppppppp
rnbqkbnr
```

but need to be:

```
RNBQKBNR
PPPPPPPP
........
........
........
........
pppppppp
rnbqkbnr
```

I do not understand how to put `'.'` char in my `StringBuilder`. Please help me.

Comment: You're already putting items in the StringBuilder. `"."` are no different. There must be more to your question that you aren't explaining.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be appending "." in any point in your code.
While not the smartest thing you can do, one possible way would be to

```
for (int number = 8; number >= 1; number--) {
  if(number > 2 && number < 7){ //if between 3 and 6
    for (char letter = 'H'; letter >= 'A'; letter--) {
      stringBuilder.append(".");
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this code only works for the original disposition of pieces in the beginning of the game. If you want to make it dynamic, you will have to check (for every location in the board) if there is a piece in that position, and the code would be

```
if( there is piece){
   stringBuilder.append(chessPiece.toChar());
}
else
   stringBuilder.append(".");
```

Comment: if you will put this if in for each. This do not work.

Comment: Obviously the if stands as pseudocode, I don't know how the project was developed overall, the point here is, if there is a piece in a certain position, add the piece to the StringBuilder, if not, add a "." .